# Excel macro: Code for combining data from specific worksheets and refresh?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has about 20 sheets. 11 of the sheets are data-based have external connections that update and add lines of data as entries are added and the workbook is refreshed. The other worksheets are sheets for tables and charts. I am trying to use vba to combine the data from the 11 data-based sheets only into one sheet and then also have the combined sheet refresh and update as more entries are added to the individual 11 sheets.

I have a code that combines the specific 11 sheets, however, I need help on the refresh part. I tried adding a button that would re-run the code, but it deletes and re-adds a combined sheet, which messes up all my references in my formulas. I'm hoping for someone to be able to re-write some of the code so that the combined sheet doesn't get deleted and a new one doesn't have to be added, and so that data can be updated into the combined sheet without screwing the references.

Thanks.

Here is the code I have so far...

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Delete the sheet "CombinedReport" if it exist
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CombinedReport").Cells.ClearContents
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a worksheet with the name "CombinedReport"
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.name = "CombinedReport"

'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("UCDP", "UCD", "ULDD", "PE-WL", "eMortTri", "eMort", "EarlyCheck", "DU", "DO", "CDDS", "CFDS"))

        Last = DestSh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        'Fill in the range that you want to copy
        Set CopyRng = sh.UsedRange
        Set CopyRng = CopyRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count - 1, CopyRng.Columns.Count)

        'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
        If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
            GoTo ExitTheSub
        End If

        'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
        'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

Next
ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Writing a reliable "updates only" script is going to be more tricky than writing your original "compile" code - for example you need to decide what represents the unique "key" for each row, so you can tell what was added/deleted/updated.

Comment: @TimWilliams Would it be possible for a few line of my code to be altered? I'm hoping that the lines where the Destsh gets added/deleted could be removed and replaced with lines that just clear the content of the sheet and then re combine the other sheets

Comment: Don't you have formulas on that sheet though?  I thought that was the issue here.